# Insert Functionality on Trigger on a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger on a view that updates a different table with a set value from the insert when a row is inserted into the view.

I have the following tables:

```
Create Table test1
(
Label varchar(255)
);

Create view test1view
as select * from test1

Create Table test2
(
Label2 varchar(255)
)
```

I have then attempted to do this by using the following trigger:

```
Create Trigger testtrigger
on Test1View
Instead of Insert
AS
Insert Into test2
(Label2)
Select Label From Inserted
```

The insert function that I'm testing with:

```
Insert Into test1 (Label)
VALUES ('1')
```

However this hasn't worked. I'm not receiving any error, it simply isn't populating the test2 table.

Can you please advise?

Comment: What do you man "hasn't worked"?  Is there an error?  What behavior do you get?  What does the `insert` statement look like?

Comment: @GordonLinoff   I've updated the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You need to insert into the VIEW for the trigger to work:

```
Insert Into test1View (Label)
    VALUES ('1');
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f5e581b7d55aced272c7dba29fdd8341) is a db<>fiddle.

Or, alternatively, you could put the trigger on the base table.

Comment: Unfortunately there's a restraint that causes me to be unable to apply the trigger to the base table. The insert function is also an automated piece and not something I have control of. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @Revokez . . . You need to insert into the entity that has the trigger.  That's pretty simple.  Either write the correct insert or put the trigger on the table that you are inserting into.

Comment: I've explained that your suggested solution wouldn't work due to the constraints I've outlined. So unfortunately your suggestion doesn't help here.

Comment: @Revokez . . . And I would like to note that this is the correct answer to your question, even if you have strangeness in your environment that doesn't let you implement it.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the question to clarify the restrictions.

Comment: @Revokez . . . (1) Modifying the question invalidates my answer, which I consider to be rude (it attracts downvotes).  (2) You cannot do what you want to do.  You cannot insert into one entity and have that trigger something on another entity.  That is not how databases work.

Comment: Understood. It sounds like I may be completely going in the wrong direction with this problem and will have to go back to the drawing board. Thanks for your assistance, I'll re-edit the original question and leave it as it was.